# Generated AWS PresignedPost does not include correct url / fields

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I am attempting to upload a file to an AWS S3 bucket via a presigned post.

When I generate a `PresignedPost` on the server using the AWS SDK for Ruby (Version 3), I do not receive back the correct url and fields for the client to make a successful POST request.

Generating the `PresignedPost` in ruby:

```rb
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region: public_bucket_region,
  credentials: public_bucket_credentials
)

aws_bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new(
  public_bucket_name,
  client: client
)

request = aws_bucket.presigned_post(
  key: 'some-random-key',
  acl: 'public-read',
  expires: Time.zone.now + 5.minutes
)

puts request.url
=> "https://bucket-name.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"

puts request.fields
=>
{
  Expires: "Wed, 30 Oct 2019 16:53:01 GMT",
  acl: "public-read",
  key: 'some-random-key'
}
```

As per the documentation, all I should have to do at this point is make a POST request to the returned URL, including the field data in the body.

However, this is clearly not enough, I get an access denied error message. I expected the URL to contain the access key id, signature, policy etc?

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

The `POST` request is being constructed as such (in a React Native app), I realise I need some extra things in the body / headers but my presigned post doesn't seem to be returning anything useful in `request.fields`:

```js
const body = new FormData();
Object.entries(request.fields).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  body.append(k, v);
});
body.append('file', file);

await fetch(request.url, {
  method: 'post',
  body: body
});
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby but what if you create your bucket object using: aws_bucket = client.bucket(public_bucket_name) and then request the pre-signed URL?

Comment: Pre-signed `POST` does not put anything in the URL other than the path, which is always `/`.  Everything is in the form body.

Comment: can you have a look at the params that are sent with the post request? The SDK should be populating the headers with the pertinent values.

Comment: Ahh thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I think I was confusing it with a `PUT`. The thing is, the `fields` the pre-signed post is returning only include three things: `Expires`, `acl` and `key` - there's no policy, signature or access key. If I just pass these three things in as form data, I get an access denied error.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - I've added some extra information in my original post!

Comment: are you able to do a `hello world` post request using the AWS SDK WITHOUT using the form constructed by the react app? The post request sent by the AWS SDK will have all the relevant tokens / keys added in the request headers, which you may not be porting over into the form you are creating in your native react app. the form you are creating in your react app will need those keys. You will have to pass them in to your react app as a "flag" not sure what you would call it in react, but in elm, they are called "flags".

Comment: @jarmod I've tried creating the bucket directly on the resource a la https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/ruby-s3-upload_object_presigned_url.rb.html, but still no luck.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon good idea - I'll give this a go, thanks!

Comment: @abigailmcphillips I would suggest to start even simpler: get a simple GET request working. Then add on the compexity of a simple post request.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got this working by creating the presigned post like this:

```rb
Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new(
  public_bucket_credentials,
  public_bucket_region,
  public_bucket_name,
  {
    key: 'some-random-key',
    acl: 'public-read',
    expires: Time.zone.now + 5.minutes
  }
)
```

Then everything I needed (access key, signature and policy) is returned in the `fields` key of the returned presigned post. No change needed to the React code.

Looks like the way I was setting up the client and then creating a bucket was not passing through the credentials needed to create a workable presigned post (I'm not really sure why AWS should allow this to happen...).

Anyway, it's working now! Thanks to everyone for their help.